# Is my GPIO pin fried?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I have a piece of code that toggles the GP2 pin on a PIC12F615 and suddenly it started producing a weird waveform, I'm not sure what I've done that could cause this. I isolated the code that toggles the pin alone in a new project to see if I'm doing something wrong but I still get the same result.

Here's the waveform:

[image]
And here's the code

```
void main(void)
{
    __delay_ms(10);

    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        PORTAbits.GP2 = 0;
        __delay_us(55);
        PORTAbits.GP2 = 1;
        __delay_us(55);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Increase the time between the toggles

Comment: Still the same :/

Comment: Try a different pin.

Comment: How are you probing the pin? If it is floating or similar you might be seeing the capacitance unloading through the scope probe.

Comment: What do you have connected on the pin?

Comment: nickagian - just the scope.

Switched to a different pin just to test it and the waveform is just fine. Problem is I don't have any unused pins on my project.

Comment: It **looks** like the transistor that sinks (NMOS) is broken. Because it's not happening, the capacitance is discharging through the probe by the **looks** of it. But I'll second @EugeneSh. and ask you to test another pin as well.

Comment: Usually fried transistors will go short so you'll see something intermediate, but maybe you fried the metalization or something. Try another chip.

Comment: But the pin is still usable if you just use a pull down resistor on that pin. Say 2k ohm resistor tied to ground.

Comment: General rule of electronics... If it worked before and it does not work now... what did you do in between. If the pin is attached to something check the circuit loads. If not, what else did you change. It could also always be static discharge if you are not following proper ESD protection techniques.

Comment: Harry Svensson - you were right, it isn't pulling it down. I added a 1.8k resistor and now I get an almost perfect square wave.
If you add this as an answer I will accept it as the correct.

Comment: @John your fix is a Band-Aid at best. If it's ESD damage you will be VERY lucky if that's all that broke. Life expectancy of the device as a whole may be severely compromised.

Comment: @Trevor I just hope it lasts until the replacement arrives :)

Comment: I'd highly recommend spending some time figuring out how your pin got fried. If it happened once, it will probably happen again.

Comment: @MathieuL. I assume it was just me handling it incorrectly. Probably from scratching my head all day long trying to figure out while my code doesn't work, only to touch it after and fry the GPIO pins and make it even worse :P

Comment: You really should be using anti-static protection. Even a jury rigged bit of wire wrapped round your wrist with a 1meg resistor at the other end to a decent ground will help.

Comment: @John - "I assume it was just me handling it incorrectly." While ESD damage is possible, of course, the damage could also have been caused by external devices or connections, which is why I asked for a schematic in [your question yesterday, related to this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/320257/everything-stops-working-after-i-enable-pwm). :-) Glad you've now found a reason for the odd behaviour you explained. :-)

Comment: @SamGibson Heh its a small world after all. I was too lazy after work to draw a schematic because its all on a breadboard. I know not the best practice, but I usually build the circuit in parts, and after I'm sure a part works, I draw it/add it to the schematic.

Comment: @John - All understood :-) The problem is that, as several people have already said, the damage *might* have been caused by what is/was attached to that pin. Unless you are confident that you've eliminated that possibility, then you might repeat the damage to the replacement device, and without a schematic, readers can't help with that analysis. :-( Anyway, good luck and thanks for providing the scope trace and the minimal test case - it really helped with the diagnosis!

Comment: @SamGibson I have no idea what might have caused the problem but I think it was just me hanlding it without proper ESD protection, since the only thing connected to that pin was my oscilloscope. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the transistor that sinks (NMOS) is broken. Because it's not happening, the capacitance is discharging through the probe by the looks of it.

But the pin is still usable if you just use a pull down resistor on that pin. Say 2k ohm resistor tied to ground.